# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler;

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I try to integrate my module(for Android) to titanium app.

I Integrade it and after i added in tiapp.xml:

```
<modules>
        <module platform="android" version="1">com.android.manager</module>
 </modules>
```

I get error:

```
[ERROR] System Error while compiling Android classes.dex
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler;
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
[ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
[ERROR] 1 error; aborting
```

Comment: the main problem was, that the name in: {code} @Kroll.module(name="SensorManager", id="com.android.manager")         the id was not the same it was: com.android.manager.Name......

Answer (score 0):

the main problem was, that the name in: {code} @Kroll.module(name="SensorManager", id="com.android.manager") the id was not the same it was: com.android.manager.Name......